# How to create two text columns in PDF?

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, pdf, core-text

The problem is to create two text columns in PDF like this:
[image: two independent text columns]
For generating PDF I use Apple's guide *"Drawing and Printing Guide for iOS"*, two columns I create with tabs:

```
NSArray *stringList =
    @[
      @[string1, string2],
      @[@"", string4],
      @[string5, string6],
      @[string7, string8]
    ];

    resultString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
    for (NSArray *row in stringList) {
        int i = 0;
        NSMutableAttributedString *subResult = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *tabs = @[].mutableCopy;
        NSMutableParagraphStyle *style = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
        for (NSString *tempString in row) {
            NSTextTab *tab = [[NSTextTab alloc] initWithTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentLeft location:200 options:nil];
            if ([tempString isKindOfClass:[NSAttributedString class]]) {
                [subResult appendAttributedString:(NSAttributedString *)tempString];
                [subResult appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\t"]];
            } else {
                [subResult appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\t", tempString]]];
            }
            [tabs addObject:tab];
            i++;
        }
        [subResult appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"\n"]];
        [style setTabStops:tabs];
        [subResult addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName
                          value:style
                          range:NSMakeRange(0, subResult.length)];
        [resultString appendAttributedString:subResult];
    }
```

As output I get this:

[image]
So, the lines of my string marked with red arrows I want see entirely in the second column, like in the picture №1.

Comment: There really isn't enough information here to help you - a .plist is just an XML file, so you need to elaborate: Are you having issues pulling values from the .plist, or creating a PDF?

Comment: @davbryn The problem is in creating PDF. I know how to draw simple strings one by one but I don't understand how to mark up text in PDF, how to make indents, paragraphs, etc.

Comment: Did you ever figure this?

Comment: @markturnip Yes, do you need the solution?

Comment: @SashaKid: Yes, we would all love to see the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea is to split the text into blocks and single lines and to use for each part

```
- (void)drawInRect:(CGRect)rect;
```

or

```
void CTLineDraw(CTLineRef line, CGContextRef context);
```

Solution:

```
@import CoreText;

<...>

- (IBAction)createPDF:(id)sender {
    PDFFileName = <yourString>;
    PDFPath = <yourPath>;
    [self generatePdfWithFilePath:PDFPath];
}

- (void)generatePdfWithFilePath:(NSString *)thefilePath {
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToFile(thefilePath, CGRectZero, nil);
    BOOL done = NO;
    do {
        UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, 612, 712), nil);
        [self drawText];
        done = YES;
    }
    while (!done);
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
}

- (void)drawText {
    CGContextRef currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    //Here you can set up attributes for your text
    NSDictionary *attributesForText = @{
                                        NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:12]
                                        };

    //Drawing text in line
    NSMutableAttributedString *stringOneAttributed = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringOne attributes:attributesForText];
    CTLineRef stringOneLine = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString((__bridge CFAttributedStringRef)(stringOneAttributed));
    CGContextSetTextPosition(currentContext, x, y);
    CTLineDraw(stringOneLine, currentContext);
    CFRelease(stringOneLine);

    //Drawing block of text in rectangle
    NSMutableAttributedString *stringTwoAttributed = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:stringTwo attributes:attributesForText];
    [stringTwoAttributed drawInRect:CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)];
}
```